# How to find a similar file to a given file into a directory with returned value of diff command?

Tags: bash, shell, diff

I am looking for a way to find one/multiple files that is/are identical to a given file. I would like to perform this with `bash shell` using the commands `find` and `diff`

I have tried the following thing into my `bash shell` :

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name  'Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat'); do if [ diff "$i" "./XSAF_LSST /SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat" -eq 0 ]; then echo "MATCHING" $i; fi; done
```

The file to find is similar to the reference file                                         `Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat`

But I get only the following error at execution :

```
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments
bash: [: too many arguments 
bash: [: too many arguments
...
```

I suspect the returned value of `diff` command is different from `0` when 2 files are identical.

As I said at the beginning, I would like to find where is my error in the command line that I have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `[` `]` or `-eq 0` when testing the result of a command. Just write `if <command>` directly.

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name  'Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat'); do
    if diff "$i" "./XSAF_LSST /SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat"; then
        echo "MATCHING" $i
    fi
done
```

Then, avoid looping over the results of `find`. It's not whitespace-safe. A path with spaces in it will cause errors. In your case, you can put use `find -exec` to combine the `find` and `diff` commands.

```
find . -type f -name Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat \
    -exec diff {} "./XSAF_LSST /SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat" \; \
    -exec echo "MATCHING" {} \;
```

Then I'd replace the `-exec echo` with `-print`.

```
find . -type f -name Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat \
    -exec diff {} "./XSAF_LSST /SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat" \; \
    -print
```

Better yet, use `diff -s` to report when files are the same. Then there's no need to even check the result.

```
find . -type f -name Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat \
    -exec diff -s {} "./XSAF_LSST /SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat" \;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have just added : `find . -type f -name 'Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat' -exec diff -qs {} "./XSAF_LSST/SAVE_WP_Pk_qui_ont_permis_de_voir_la_concordance_entre_Totally_et_XSAF_13_JUIN_2019/WP_Pk/h_up/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk_iz_10.dat" \; | grep -v differ` to get only the filename of same ones. Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for matches and don't care about the differences, don't use `diff`.
Use `cmp` with the `-s`/`--quiet`/`--silent` option(s).

```
basefile="./your/Really/Long/File/Path/name"
while read -r filepath
do if cmp -s "$basefile" "$filepath"
   then echo "SAME: $filepath"
   else : why report all these??
   fi
done < <( find . -type f )
```

Comment: This is also faster because `cmp` will exit as soon as it finds a single byte of difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compare the exit code of your diff command and not its output. You can access the exit code through $?. You can then set a variable based on this exit code and output it.

```
for i in $(find . -type f) # this will return a list of files
  do 
    diff Pks8..._10.dat $i &>/dev/null # return code is 0 for identical files
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then # here you compare the exit code. Is it 0?
      ret="same"
    else # if it wasn't 0 the files were different
      ret="different"
    fi
  echo $i $ret
done
```

Hope this helps to fix your code.